# Can not connect online accounts - options are greyed out

Tags: 20.04, online-accounts, accounts

I'm trying to connect my Google and Microsoft accounts but seems like the function is deactivated. Clicking the three dots didn't work.

[image: Deactivated option]

Comment: Not sure does this helps. It might be due to some deamon that is not enabled/started.
I had the same issue once that my ubuntu budgie extras was disabled until I update it and reenable it. Was long time a go so can't help for sure...